# ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField in Chrome

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with some code that utilizes the ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField to keep track of modifications to a datamodel.  It works fine in IE and FF, but Chrome is having trouble.  A simple example of the problem occurs if you add something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, DateTime.Now.ToString(), "keith");
}
```

on a page.  When you first load the page it works correctly, you will see a hidden field like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="12/17/2010 9:55:13 AM" id="12/17/2010 9:55:13 AM" value="keith" />
```

However, if you do anything that requires a post back it will not generate a new date/time for the name of the hidden field.  It usually generates a cached version of the field from hours before.  Any thoughts on why Chrome performs this way with RegisterHiddenField?  Thank you for any help.

Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is actually caching the "view source".

If you look in the url you will see something like "view-source:http://localhost:51966/Default.aspx"

Hit the refresh button and you will see your hidden field change.

Comment: Haha wow was not expecting such a simple answer.  Thanks Jimmy.

Comment: Glad it was easy. Totally gave someone a wrong answer earlier this morning :-)