# Why is the HiddenField value concatenating with the old value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

Suddenly my application has some problems when getting the hiddenfield values on server side.
My Code that was running before this sudden event;

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfColumnName" runat="server" />
```

in the code behind I use to get and set its values like;

```
if(hfColumnName.Value == SortDirection.Ascending.ToString())
{
    //have logic to perform.
    hfColumnName.Value = SortDirection.Ascending.ToString();
}
else(hfColumnName.Value == SortDirection.Descending.ToString())
{
    //have logic to perform.
    hfColumnName.Value = SortDirection.Descending.ToString();
}
```

When next time this code runs, the hidden field value contains the concatenated values of its old and new one.

Comment: Seems you are playing with `hfColumnName` on Client side as well..

Comment: I tried adding a new HiddenField. But same result

Comment: What changes did you do recently before this bug occurred?

Comment: I added the this file from my other project to this working project. By copying the file from its destination and pasted in the Forms folder this solution.

Comment: try putting in an <asp:label/> with visible=false, and set it's value instead of hiddenfield. Then check if it still concats the value like in the hiddenfield. Are you using UpdatePanel? Is the hiddenfield inside the updatepanel?

Comment: But when I changed HiddenField to span like this, it works<span id="hfColumnName" runat="server" style="display:none"></span>

Comment: Yes, my hiddenfield is in the updatepanel. I have only a single update panel and my all these controls are in it.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour, and I would also suggest that you are doing something with the hidden object.  Probably a stupid question (and assuming you're using Visual Studio or another IDE) have you tried doing a "Find in Files" for the object name?  Do you have any code (server-side or client-side) that is looking for hidden field objects and amending them (i.e. not looking for the name, but for the object type)?

Comment: Yeah I know that should be in UpdatePanel.
@freefaller Stupid is the visual studio IDE I think, not the question.
Because I have been working and using HiddenField for several years.

Comment: Ok, What is the updatemode of UpdatePanel? If you set it to "Always", what happens?

Comment: I have already tested with setting both "Always" and "Conditional".

Comment: At a loss here. One last thing. Try using RegisterHiddenField of scriptmanager. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471690/scriptmanager-registerhiddenfield-in-chrome and this http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t98394-registerhiddenfield-question.html

Comment: Sorry Tranceporter, same result.

Comment: From the code you provided "ASPX" the hidden element doesn't contains the any value. and in the code behind you used conditions to set the data. Could you please let me know are you setting the data for hidden element in client side else let me know how hidden element value get set in code behind satifying any conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The root cause was  html/asp code some improper tags. Please make sure the tag is proper.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1448466/3304601.aspx#3304601

Comment: Would be helpful to other users, if you include what improper tags were the root cause, etc.